# Android Geofencing Not Triggering in some mobile like OnePlus, Xiaomi etc

Tags: android, android-geofence

Am using Geo-fencing code under guidelines of Android document. Tested in Real device such as Sony XA1, Samsung J7 Nxt, Xiaomi 5A, Poco f1, OnePlus 6. Geo-fencing **Enter** and **Exit** are working Properly in Sony XA1, Samsung J7 Nxt.

Issues in **Xiaomi** & **OnePlus** Mobile.

1. In Xiaomi 5A Some time **Enter** working properly but **Exit** not triggering.
2. In Xiaomi Poco f1 Both **Enter** and **Exit** are not working.
3. In OnePlus Mobile works only when app is open.

**Geo-Fencing Code:**

```
private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;
private ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(getApplicationContext());

//Latitude & Longitude Comes from Array to Add
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId(String.valueOf(mall.mallId)).setCircularRegion(
              mall.latitude,
              mall.longitude,
              mall.geofencingMeters)
             .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
             .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
             .build());

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {

    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);

    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, FENCING_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * Receives incoming intents.
     *
     * @param context the application context.
     * @param intent  sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *                Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Enqueues a JobIntentService passing the context and intent as parameters
        StoreFencing.enqueueWork(context, intent);
    }
  }
}
```

**Fencing Service:**

```
public class StoreFencing extends JobIntentService {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 502;
    List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, StoreFencing.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {

            return;
        }

        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

            triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
            getGeofenceEnterTransitionDetails(triggeringGeofences);

        }

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
            getGeofenceExitTransitionDetails(triggeringGeofences);

        }

    }
}
```

Is there any problem in Code or Device. Inform users to enable additional setting in these mobile. Help to Solve this Issue.

Comment: fucking chinese device always work differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have also experienced these issues.

1. On One Plus devices, battery optimization for your app must be disabled, i.e. it must be set to 'Dont optimize' in the Settings > Battery > All apps > YourApp. Only then it will work when your app is in background or not even in background.
2. On Xiaomi devices, your app must have auto-start permission enabled in the settings for geofencing to work correctly.
3. Most other Chinese devices such as Lenovo, Coolpad, etc. have also not triggering any geofence transition events after the app has been killed from the recents.

You can redirect the user to the specific page in settings and tell them to enable/disable them for geofencing to work correctly.

Other than that I have not found any solution.

Also you can check these [Geofence Troubleshing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using Broadcast Receivers as these are targets for Battery optimization from Oreo and above. So using the fusedLocationProvider is the recommended way. Also instead of calling the Geofencing API, it would better use the Haversine Formula(Used to calculate distance between to coordinates)

```
LatLng Home = new LatLng(10.398152, 76.096864);
int Radius =100;
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        //Haversine formula
        
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude() - Home.longitude;
                        double latitude  = location.getLatitude() - Home.latitude;
                        double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(latitude/2),2) + Math.cos(Home.latitude)
                                *Math.cos(location.getLatitude())*Math.pow(Math.sin(longitude/2),2);
                        double circuit = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                        double eradius = 6371;
                       if(circuit*eradius<Radius){
                           Log.e("User Status","Within Geofence");
                           
                                                  }
    else{
    Log.e("User Status","User outside Geofence");
    }
```