# Geofence breach on android is not much reliable

Tags: android, android-geofence, geofence

We are facing several issues with geofence breaches on android especially on non Google pixel devices like Samsung, Motorola, Huawei. Basically geofence does not breach all the times and only during some instances.

We are using the recommended approach here https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing to implement the geofence addition/removal.

How reliable is the geofence breach algorithm on android ?

We are using the recommended approach here https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing to implement the geofence addition/removal. And expecting geofence breaches to happen reliably.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631565/android-geofencing-not-triggering-in-some-mobile-like-oneplus-xiaomi-etc